# Postgres sync from multiple IOT devices

Tags: postgresql

Im new to Postgres and am playing with the concept of a remote monitoring network which consist of  multiple unique Windows IOT devices.
Each of these devices has a Postgres database that consists of a default schema set.
Some of these IOT devices are setup in remote areas with flaky connections, hence the local database to ensure data is stored.

I want all of these devices to push their data, preferably every 10 seconds, to a central Postgres database (windows or linux based) in a central office.

Can some one point me in the right direction how to do this, especially with regards to the following:

1. would you use streaming or master/slave replication (or another option)?
2. what (third party) application (pglogical or....) would be used to setup this replication?

Comment: I have a very similar use case and question!

Comment: @LiveSource

I totally forgot about this question, so below my solution.

Establish inet connection on IOT devices
Create vpns to the central postgres host network on each client as I didnt have a fixed ip and wasnt going to use dyndns.
On the IOT devices in postgres I published the database tables of interest.
On the host postgres I subscribed to each IOT device
https://hevodata.com/learn/postgresql-logical-replication/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@LiveSource

I totally forgot about this question, so below my solution.

1. Establish inet connection on IOT devices
2. Create vpns to the central postgres host network on each client as I didnt
   have a fixed ip and wasnt going to use dyndns.
3. On the IOT devices in postgres I published the database tables of
   interest.
4. On the host postgres I subscribed to each IOT device

https://hevodata.com/learn/postgresql-logical-replication/